# How does Clojure loop form works?

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure an Functional Programming both.
I tried my best, understanding the loop construct.

I can use it, I can look at a code written with it and tell the output but what I dont understand is,How does it work ?

is it same as writing an anonymous function with parameters and then keeping recur at the tail with same arity and new values ?

is it an inbuilt macro or something for it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, `loop` is not a function or a macro.  It is a [special form](http://clojure.org/special_forms).  It works just like `let` (which is also a special form) except that it acts as a target for `recur`.

One way to differentiate functions, macros, and special forms is to examine how their arguments are evaluated:

- Function arguments are always evaluated, and then the results are passed to the function.
- Macro arguments are not evaluated until the macro expands to a new unevaluated form.
- Special form arguments are not evaluated when passed, but the special form may or may not choose to evaluate them internally.

Comment: so what does it return ? like do, the last expression ?

Comment: Yes: `(loop [x 1] (if (< x 5) (recur (inc x)) x))` => 5

Comment: recur will always target the nearest loop,defn or fn form ?

Comment: Yes. `defn` is just a macro which expands to a form using `fn`.

Answer (score 5):

**dbyrne**'s answer is all true, and good, but I'd like to address your further question "Is it the same as writing an anonymous function with parameters and then `recur` at the tail with same arity and new values?". Yes, it is exactly like that:

```
(loop [x 1, y 2]
  (if (whatever x y)
    (recur (inc x) (dec y))
    (* x y)))
```

is functionally identical to

```
((fn [x y]
   (if (whatever x y)
     (recur (inc x) (dec y))
     (* x y)))
 1 2)
```

If `loop` didn't exist, you could write it as a simple macro that emits this sort of form, but the compiler has a special `loop` form which is faster.

```
(defmacro loop [bindings & body]
  (let [bindings (partition 2 bindings)]
    `((fn [~@(map first bindings)]
        (do ~@body))
      ~@(map second bindings))))
```

Comment: that was a confidence booster.
I am writing all those programming problems and algorithms, I did in my early programming days with for-loops and while-loops in C,C++ and Java the clojure way.

That makes sure that I understood the concept the write way :)

I loved recur form, which means I can now recursively call an anonymous method as well, i dont need to specify a name.

Is the same possible in JavaScript or Python ?